# What are simple options to provide user with possibility to sort results?

Tags: django, sorting, django-templates, django-views

Suppose that I'm creating real-estate agency web page. The offer page initially displays offers ordered by `pub_date`. I would like to enable users to sort offers by `price` or `floor_space`.

E.g.:

Models.py:

```
class Offer(models.Model):

    city = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    nb_rooms = models.IntegerField()
    floor_space = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
```

Views.py:

```
def flats(request):
    flat_offers = Offer.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
    context_dict = {
        'flat_offers': flat_offers,
        }
    return render(request, 'cardom/flats.html', context_dict)
```

Template:

```
{% for offer in flat_offers %}
    <table class="table_center">
        <tr><th>{{offer.category}}</th></tr>
        <tr><td><div class="location">{{offer.city}} ({{offer.district}})</div></td></tr>
        <tr><td><img src="{{ offer.main_image.url }}" height="180" width="270" alt="error"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><div class="info"><p class="text-left">{{offer.floor_space}}m2</p><p class="text-center">{{offer.get_transaction_display}}</p><p class="text-right">{{offer.price}}zł </p></div></td></tr>
    </table><br />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You can pass GET parameters in your view method, then fill in order_by() method accordingly.